# In Transit - Value of Goods

Tags: usa, transit, customs-and-immigration, import-taxes

There's a question in a customs declaration form asking the "Total Value of goods that will remain in the US", since I'm only in the US for a layover to Canada and I'm not leaving anything in the US just waiting for my next flight, will I put "0"?

Comment: This is not the first time I've had to say it on t.se: food already in your stomach has a value of $0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exactly. If you're not leaving anything in the US, $0 is the value of the goods remaining the US (because there aren't any). If you aren't sure about something on the form, you can always ask the officers too.

Comment: Will I still need to declare the goods I'm carrying with me even if I'm not taking them out? For example, I'm bringing a lot of food, they won't remain in the US, but I have them with me, so I'll be declaring that on the back of the customs form, right? Will I pay anything for those?

Comment: @millionsuns The section on the back of the form is really meant to itemize the stuff you're declaring on the front. If you have food though, you'll need to check the box on the front (question 11a) that says you're bringing food and show the food to the officers. You'll need to declare any food to the Canadian authorities as well. Don't bring any food, especially food that isn't commercially packaged, you're not prepared to lose. You shouldn't pay any duty (to the US) on food that you're not leaving in the US.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm well aware of customs processes in Canada but not in the US. I'm a Canadian resident so I have an $800 exemption in Canada so no problem with the stuff I'm bringing in. Also all the food I'm bringing in are allowable ones only. However, I panicked because I thought that since I'll be going through the US that I'd have to pay duties for the stuff I'm carrying.